# XQuery T-sql insert node into all elements

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I want to insert a single node into all elements of ans XML variable without having to use a cursor.  I'm using an xml variable here, but will be run on a table.  I will need to run this every few days or so and I don't want to add duplicate elements. I tested using "if", but it didn't seem to work without an "else" and I couldn't find like an "else do nothing".  BTW, I can't change the xml format.

Here is the xml:

```
Declare @xml xml =
'<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<DataObject>
    <Objects>
        <Object Name="FirstName" Value="John" />
        <Object Name="LastName" Value="Smith" />
        <Object Name="City" Value="Miami" />
        <Object Name="State" Value="FL" />
        <Object Name="Department" Value="HR" />
    </Objects>
</DataObject>
<DataObject>
    <Objects>
        <Object Name="FirstName" Value="Jane" />
        <Object Name="LastName" Value="Doe" />
        <Object Name="City" Value="Hollywood" />
        <Object Name="State" Value="FL" />
        <Object Name="Department" Value="Accounting" />
    </Objects>
</DataObject>'
```

In pseudo code, I want to say

```
Insert <Object Name="Zip" Value="" />
Into all <DataObject/Objects>
After "all" (//DataObject/Objects/Object[@Name="State"])
Where not exixt (<Object Name="Zip" Value="" />)
```

In other words, I want to add the Zip node to all Object elements that don't already have a zip node.  I want to do this with one statement instead of having to use a cursor.

Is this even possible?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: I added the tag `[sql-server]` (assuming this from your code and the tag `tsql]`). It would be nice to add another tag with the actual RDBMS together with the version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the tag [tsql] and the given sample I assume this is SQL-Server. Please do not forget to tag your next question accordingly (product and version).

The very limited `.modify()` function does allow for one single change per call.

The best approach depends a lot on the actual issue...

You might walk the [FLWOR route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/flwor-statement-and-iteration-xquery?view=sql-server-ver15):

First I declare a mockup table with three rows. One row is your sample, one row has got one Zip already and the third has got ZIPs in both XML fragments.

```
Declare @mockupTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, SomeDescription VARCHAR(100), YourXml XML);
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES
('Your sample, no Zip codes',
'<DataObject>
    <Objects>
        <Object Name="FirstName" Value="John" />
        <Object Name="LastName" Value="Smith" />
        <Object Name="City" Value="Miami" />
        <Object Name="State" Value="FL" />
        <Object Name="Department" Value="HR" />
    </Objects>
</DataObject>
<DataObject>
    <Objects>
        <Object Name="FirstName" Value="Jane" />
        <Object Name="LastName" Value="Doe" />
        <Object Name="City" Value="Hollywood" />
        <Object Name="State" Value="FL" />
        <Object Name="Department" Value="Accounting" />
    </Objects>
</DataObject>')
,('One has a zip code already',
'<DataObject>
    <Objects>
        <Object Name="FirstName" Value="John" />
        <Object Name="LastName" Value="Smith" />
        <Object Name="City" Value="Miami" />
        <Object Name="State" Value="FL" />
        <Object Name="Zip" Value="12345" />
        <Object Name="Department" Value="HR" />
    </Objects>
</DataObject>
<DataObject>
    <Objects>
        <Object Name="FirstName" Value="Jane" />
        <Object Name="LastName" Value="Doe" />
        <Object Name="City" Value="Hollywood" />
        <Object Name="State" Value="FL" />
        <Object Name="Department" Value="Accounting" />
    </Objects>
</DataObject>')
,('Both have zip codes',
'<DataObject>
    <Objects>
        <Object Name="FirstName" Value="John" />
        <Object Name="LastName" Value="Smith" />
        <Object Name="City" Value="Miami" />
        <Object Name="State" Value="FL" />
        <Object Name="Zip" Value="12345" />
        <Object Name="Department" Value="HR" />
    </Objects>
</DataObject>
<DataObject>
    <Objects>
        <Object Name="FirstName" Value="Jane" />
        <Object Name="LastName" Value="Doe" />
        <Object Name="City" Value="Hollywood" />
        <Object Name="State" Value="FL" />
        <Object Name="Zip" Value="12345" />
        <Object Name="Department" Value="Accounting" />
    </Objects>
</DataObject>');
```

--This is the query

```
SELECT t.*
      ,t.YourXml.query
      ('
       for $os in /DataObject/Objects
       return
        <DataObject>
        <Objects>
        {
            for $o in $os/Object
            return
            if(empty($os[Object[@Name="Zip"]]) and $o[@Name="State"]) then
              ($o,<Object Name="Zip" Value="abcde"/>)
            else
              $o
        }
        </Objects>
        </DataObject>
      ')
FROM @mockupTable t;
```

The idea in short:

We iterate through all `<Objects>` using the variable `$os`.
Now we start a second for-loop below `$os` and iterate through the contained `<Object>` elements.
The idea is: If the `$os` has NOT got an `<Object>` with the `Name` equals `Zip` (see the usage of `empty()`) and the current `<Object>` has a `Name` of `State` we are going to return the element `$o` unchanged but together with a new element to insert the `Zip`-element right after the one with "State".
In any other case we just return the `$o` thus returning everything *as is*.

You can use this created XML in a simple UPDATE and update your tabel in one single call.

### UPDATE

The code to update the entire table in one call

```
WITH updatableCTE AS
(
    SELECT t.YourXml 
          ,t.YourXml.query
          ('
           for $os in /DataObject/Objects
           return
            <DataObject>
            <Objects>
            {
                for $o in $os/Object
                return
                if(empty($os[Object[@Name="Zip"]]) and $o[@Name="State"]) then
                  ($o,<Object Name="Zip" Value="abcde"/>)
                else
                  $o
            }
            </Objects>
            </DataObject>
          ') AS NewContent
    FROM @mockupTable t
)
UPDATE updatableCTE SET YourXml=NewContent;

--check the result
SELECT * FROM @mockupTable
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I think I'm following it.  Does this put the zip after state?

Comment: @FirstByte Yes, as described below the query. I just added the code to update all  in one call. Happy Coding

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!